Is there a numericInput for Shiny with min/max values similar to dateInput
I am looking for a min/max numericInput option (or similar solution) for Shiny where the user can filter data based on given min/max values, visually the slider option is not great. Is there an option for this or can it be done combining two separate numericInputs (which would need to be reactive I assume) or any other solution. The results will be used in a observeEvent to return filtered data.


There in fact is:
library(shinywidgets)

numericRangeInput(
              "bins",
              "Number of bins:",
              separator = "to",
              min = 1,
              max = 50,
              value = 0
              )
        


Just found it... thanks!

You're welcome, Wit!
